# Subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ satisfying the factorial property

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial

Consider the subset $S \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ given by:

$$S = \{ 2^i 3^j : i,j \ge 0 \}$$

Define the sequence $(a_k)$ to be the elements of $S$ in increasing order (with the standard order on $\mathbb{Z}$), and further define:

$$ [a_n]! = \prod_{k = 1}^n a_k$$

I am interested to know if this generalisation of the factorial satisfies the analogous fundamental property:

$$\frac{[a_{m+n}]!}{[a_m]![a_n]!} \in S$$

and more generally, if this relation would hold given $S$ generated as the multiplicative span of any finite set of primes.

This seems very plausible, but I haven't found it to be immediate. It is obvious if $S$ is generated by only one prime. It may not hold if $S$ is generated by infinitely many primes, as the case $S = \{1,3,5,7,9,...\}$ demonstrates.

I am aware of the Bhargava factorial corresponding to sets $S \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$, an important recently-discovered generalisation of the factorial which satisfies the property above. Unfortunately, the Bhargava factorial of $S$ is not equal to the function I have given above. But it's possible that this factorial could be realised as a Bhargava factorial of some other subset of $T \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$.

For reference, the first terms of the sequence $(a_k)$ for $S = \{2^i 3^j\}$ are $1,2,3,4,6,8,9,12,16,18,24,...$.

This gives:

$$[a_0]! = 1$$
$$[a_1]! = 1$$
$$[a_2]! = 2$$
$$[a_3]! = 6$$
$$[a_4]! = 24$$
$$[a_5]! = 144$$

Comment: You can try very famous LTE lemma!!!

Comment: Or some inductive idea through LTE lemma!!! Quiet Imteresting question.

Comment: @HappieHappieHappie Thanks for the suggestion! I'll think about it. I've never seen the lemma before, and it's quite a surprising result to me.

Comment: In your $41,43$ counterexample the sequence is $1,41,43,1681,1763,\dots$, hence $[a_5]!=1763⋅1681⋅43⋅41⋅1=41^443^2$ and similarly $[a_1]!=1$, $[a_4]!=41^3 43$, so actually $[a_1]![a_4]!$ divides $[a_5]!$

Comment: @Sil You're absolutely right, I mistakenly shifted the index by $1$ in my head. Thanks for pointing this out. I'm glad to learn that the original intuition I had that this is quite a robust idea was not misplaced.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Maybe you already know that, anyway your numbers (the $a_n$ sequence) are called $3$-smooth numbers, and the generalization to the set of primes less or equal than $k$ are called $k$-smooth numbers.

Comment: By the way this does not hold for more primes, for example $2^i 3^j 5^k$ has sequence (starting from $a_0$): $1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24, 25, 27$ and you can verify $[a_2]!=2$, $[a_{15}]!=2^{20}3^9 5^4$ and $[a_{17}]!=2^{20}3^{12}5^6$, so the condition fails at power of $2$

Comment: @BillyJoe I did not. Thanks!

Comment: @Sil Good find! I meant to edit in yesterday that the example I gave about the result not holding for infinitely many primes also shows that it does not hold for $S = \{3,5,7,11,13\}$. But your example is better; you've also disproved the modified conjecture which I was going to propose -- that it holds if $S$ is an initial subset of the primes. The more inscrutable nature of $S = \{p, q\}$ thus seems to be due to the fact that no two consecutive elements can be non-divisible by $p$ (or $q$).

Comment: I have crossposted the question (for two primes only) at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/450484/136218).

Comment: @BillyJoe Thanks! I didn't predict that this might be interesting to professionals.

Comment: I've verified the conjecture (for $2^i3^j$) up to $a_{m + n} \le 10^{50}$, which corresponds to $m + n \le 8839$. Python code: https://pastebin.com/PC88Ab4F.

Comment: @ronno Wow, thank you. There was a solution given to the question when it was crossposted to mathoverflow (see earlier comments), but it seemed dubious to me, and according to one comment, it implied that the conjecture was likely to fail for $m,n$ not much higher than $14$. I guess we could take your result as experimental evidence that the reasoning there may have been flawed. Thanks again.

Comment: @BillyJoe Perhaps this is of interest to you as well.